Flutter go_router using ShellRoute can't display overlay in correcto position
enter image description here
Flutter 3.19.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 300451adae (2 weeks ago) • 2024-03-27 21:54:07 -0500
Engine • revision e76c956498
Tools • Dart 3.3.3 • DevTools 2.31.1
import 'package:fleather/fleather.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  FleatherController controller =
      FleatherController(document: ParchmentDocument());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: GoRouter(
        initialLocation: '/',
        routes: <RouteBase>[
          ShellRoute(
            pageBuilder: (context, state, child) => NoTransitionPage(
              child: Scaffold(
                body: Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 60, left: 200),
                  child: child,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            routes: [
              GoRoute(
                path: '/',
                builder: (_, __) => Column(
                  children: [
                    FleatherToolbar.basic(controller: controller),
                    Expanded(child: FleatherEditor(controller: controller)),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

The color dialog overlay in wrong position... The cause is ShellRoute...
